# RShiny enable/disable UI modules

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinyjs

I would like to set up my Shiny app to dynamically enable/disable UI modules based on user input.  I am accustomed to using ShinyJS to do this in a non-modular app by passing the ID of the UI element into the enable() or disable() functions.  However, with the UI now being generated inside of a module, I no longer have access to the same ID.

Here is an example app which increments by 1 each time the "counter1" button is clicked.  The "counterButton" function is contained in an external module called "counterModule.R", and I would like the "toggleButton" to toggle the state of the "counterButton" between enabled and disabled.  The call to toggleState() currently does nothing I assume because the "counter1" ID is not found.  What would be the best way of going about this?

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
  mainPanel(actionButton(inputId = "toggleButton", label = "Toggle counter button"), 
  sidebarPanel(counterButton("counter1", "+1"))) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$toggleButton, {
    print("clicked toggle button")
    shinyjs::toggleState("counter1")
  })
  counterServer("counter1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

R/counterModule.R

```
counterButton <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
      actionButton(ns("button"), label = label), 
      verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

counterServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      count <- reactiveVal(0)
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        count(count() + 1)
      })
      output$out <- renderText({
        count()
      })
      count
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities. The namespacing of the shiny modules works in the following format: `namespace-elementid`. This means that your button in the module has the id `counter1-button` which is globally unique (and within in the module, you can just use `button`).

Therefore, you can use the namespaced id in your main `server` function:

```
observeEvent(input$toggleButton, {
    print("clicked toggle button")
    shinyjs::toggleState("counter1-button")
  })
```

However, this somehow breaks the separation of ui/logic defined in the module and in the main server function. Therefore, the second option is to define the toggle button in the main app, but have the toggle logic in the module:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

##########################
# code of the module
counterButton <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button"), label = label), 
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

counterServer <- function(id, toggle_action) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      count <- reactiveVal(0)
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        count(count() + 1)
      })
      output$out <- renderText({
        count()
      })
      
      observeEvent(toggle_action(), {
        print("clicked toggle button")
        shinyjs::toggleState("button")
      })
      
      count
    }
  )
}


##########################
# code of the main app
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
  mainPanel(actionButton(inputId = "toggleButton", label = "Toggle counter button"), 
            sidebarPanel(counterButton("counter1", "+1"))) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  counterServer("counter1", toggle_action = reactive({input$toggleButton}))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Knowing how module namespacing works is very helpful.  In your second code block you suggest defining the UI in the app.R file and handling the toggle functionality in the module, however it looks like everything is contained in one file.  I'm a little unclear which portion of code goes into the app.R file and which is in the counterModule.R file.  Could you separate out the portion of the code that is meant to go into the module specifically?

Comment: see my edit. You can have a separate file with the module code or just one `app.R` file as in my answer that contains both the app and the module code

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.  I should have mentioned one of the goals of modularizing my app is to cut down on the code bulk in the app.R file.  Separating it out in this way will be a big help to code readability.

Comment: definitely. On SO, I'm usually too lazy to separate it into different files, but for your project it totally makes sense